# Usar FOR en un arreglo

Tags: javascript, array

tengo las siguientes respuestas. Como puedo usar un for para estar evitando poner [0],[1],[2] etc.

```
console.log("-------------------------------");
console.log(response.output.generic[0].options[0].label);
console.log(response.output.generic[0].options[1].label);
console.log(response.output.generic[0].options[2].label);
console.log(response.output.generic[0].options[3].label);
console.log("-------------------------------");
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones:

1. `for` tradicional:

```js
let response = {};
response.output = {};
response.output.generic =[];
response.output.generic[0] = [];
response.output.generic[0].options = [{label:"Option 1"},{label:"Option 2"},{label:"Option 3"},{label:"Option 4"}];

console.log("-------------------------------");
for(let i=0;i<response.output.generic[0].options.length;i++){
  console.log(response.output.generic[0].options[i].label);
}
console.log("-------------------------------");
```

2. `for of`

```js
let response = {};
    response.output = {};
    response.output.generic =[];
    response.output.generic[0] = [];
    response.output.generic[0].options = [{label:"Option 1"},{label:"Option 2"},{label:"Option 3"},{label:"Option 4"}];

    console.log("-------------------------------");
    for(let item of response.output.generic[0].options){
      console.log(item.label);
    }
    console.log("-------------------------------");
```

3. `forEach`

```js
let response = {};
        response.output = {};
        response.output.generic =[];
        response.output.generic[0] = [];
        response.output.generic[0].options = [{label:"Option 1"},{label:"Option 2"},{label:"Option 3"},{label:"Option 4"}];

        console.log("-------------------------------");
        response.output.generic[0].options.forEach((v)=>{
          console.log(v.label);        
        });
          
        console.log("-------------------------------");
```

Personalmente `for of` me parece la más limpia de todas.

[Aquí](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/04/es6-in-depth-iterators-and-the-for-of-loop/) tienes más info sobre bucles e iteradores

Comment: Muchas muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Como `response.output.generic[0].options` es un arreglo puedes utilizar su propiedad lenght. Y ese valor utilizarlo en un ciclo for.

```
console.log("-------------------------------");
for ( let i = 0; i < response.output.generic[0].options.lenght; i++ ) {
  console.log(response.output.generic[0].options[i].label);
}
console.log("-------------------------------");
```

Comment: No imprime ningun resultado.

Comment: Es length, no lenght.

Comment: Sorry por el typo